# How to move out of directory in URL

Tags: css, url

I have following directory structure:

```
after (folder)
  images (folder)
    restaurant-logo.png (file, which I should select)

before (folder)
  css (folder)
    styles.css (file, where I am located)
```

What should I specify  `backround: url("HERE?")` to find the target image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be going back in the directory tree then go in the **after** folder to select the target image, it should be like `../../after/images/restaurant-logo.png`. Also, you can check [what is a URL?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL) to know what URL contains and how to write a URL overall.